# Specific compensation and property income figures in the national accounts

Tags: national-accounts

I have highlighted four highlighted numbers in the UN *System of National Accounts* ([p. 31, Table 2.13](https://books.google.com/books?id=gQWmAdwdI8gC&pg=PA31)). My question is: What are these numbers?

[image]

My guesses:

- 6 = Compensation paid by foreign firms to resident employees.
- 2 = Compensation paid by resident firms to foreign employees.
- 44 = Property income paid by foreigners to residents.
- 38 = Property income paid by residents to foreigners.

I'm sure the answer is somewhere in the document (700 pages and not exactly user friendly), but I can't find it.

When answering my question, please cite where in the document you found the answer.

---

Also, how is the number 1864 obtained from the numbers above?

Answer (score 0):

Para 2.43 explains the difference between the ‘uses’ and ‘resources’ sides of the account. The columns then refer to different sectors, where you are highlighting transactions with the ‘rest of the world’ sector.

[image: Para 2.43 Rules of accounting]

For the numbers you refer to, the left-hand side is uses:

6 = compensation of employees paid out to the ‘rest of the world’ sector.
44 = property income paid out to the rest of the world sector.

The right-hand side is resources:

2 = compensation of employees paid into this economy by/from the rest of the world sector.
38 = property income paid into this economy, by/from the rest of the world sector.

Edit: you also asked how the 1,864 is derived. The balancing item for this account should be calculated as total resources less total uses (although I just tried it and got 1,854). There are separate gross and net balances, where the difference is consumption of fixed capital (depreciation of assets).